# Random-walk and unit root processes predictable?

Tags: forecasting, autoregressive, unit-root, random-walk

I know that a random walk is an AR(1) with a unit root, but there are also higher order autoregressive processes with unit roots. Does the unit root in such a higher order autoregressive process also imply unpredictability (or at least that the best forecast is just the current state as for a random walk) of the time series? Are forecasts of processes with unit roots possible if it is a higher order AR-process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presence of a unit root in a higher-order autoregressive process **does not** imply unpredictability as in the case of a random walk. Here is a counterexample. If the first-differenced process is AR(1)
$$
\Delta x_{t}=\varphi\Delta x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t,
$$
then the original process is AR(2) with a unit root
$$
x_{t}=(1+\varphi)x_{t-1}-\varphi x_{t-2}+\varepsilon_t.
$$
The optimal 1-step-ahead point forecast under square loss is
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(x_t|I_{t-1}) &= (1+\varphi)x_{t-1}-\varphi x_{t-2} \\
&\not\equiv x_{t-1}.
\end{aligned}
This is an example of a higher-order AR process with a unit root for which the best prediction is not the last observed value (as would be the case for random walk).

Comment: In context of an augmented dickey fuller test, if the lag amount that exhibits the lowest information criteria is >=2 this means that the process is not necessarily unpredictable, is that correct?

Comment: @J3lackkyy, yes, I think so.